# Realm-Android object properties does not save

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Realm database does not save data.
I am trying to save an object data but when the last phase executed, an AccessToken record is saved but Account.accessToken still null.
Account class

```
public class Account extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    private AccessToken accessToken;

    public AccessToken setAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
        return this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }
}
```

AccessToken class:

```
public class AccessToken extends RealmObject {
    private long expiration_date;

    private String access_token;
    public void setExpirationDate(long expiration_date) {
        this.expiration_date = expiration_date;
    }
    public void setAccessToken(String access_token) {
        this.access_token = access_token;
    }
}
```

Realm saving data code:

```
public void changeAccountAccessToken(final Account account, final AccessToken srcAccessToken) {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            AccessToken accessToken = realm.createObject(AccessToken.class);
            accessToken.setAccessToken(srcAccessToken.getAccessToken());
            accessToken.setExpirationDate(srcAccessToken.getExpirationDate());
            account.setAccessToken(accessToken);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You didn't obtain `account` from an open `realm` instance.

Comment: public RealmResults<Account> getAccount() {
        return realm.where(Account.class).findAll();
    }

Comment: @EpicPandaForce this is my code to retrieve data from the database. Please check. Thanks

Comment: That's a RealmResults though so that's not the whole story here

Comment: I fixed it, the main reason are Account object is not managed